# Custom error messages when XSD validation fails

Tags: xml, xsd

I am validating xml file with xsd and i want to return meaningful messages to user. is there any way to build custom messages in xsd.

Answer (score 5):

The answers "no" and "yes" (or "yes, but ...") both apply here, depending on what you want; unfortunately, for all practical purposes the answer is "no".

The XSD spec does not specify or constrain APIs or user interfaces, so there is no standard way to specify, in an XSD schema document, what message to give the user if a particular constraint is violated.  It is perfectly legitimate for schema processors to allow you some way to control the error messages, and the xs:appinfo element is included in part to make things like that feasible.  But I don't know of any schema validators that actually do provide that kind of facility (I'd be glad to learn of any that do).

One possible workaround:  XSD does suggest specific error codes for use by validators, so if your validator provides an API for validation results, you may be able to identify the errors raised and use the error codes and location information to generate suitable error messages for your users.  The same may be true if your processor produces written output you can parse.

The simplest way to get nifty user-specifiable error messages, customizable based on just what has gone wrong, is to use Schematron, which does prescribe that processors use error messages specified by the schema author.  (I expect there is some handwaving somewhere to deal with internationalization, but I don't know any details.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) which uses a set of rules - each with a custom error message - to validate a document. All these error messages appear in validation report, called SVRL, together with corresponding error location (XPath) in the input document.